# Can I run the SonarQube Java Analyzer without running the scanner? And how?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I want to get the syntax and semantic info for a given Java file, and it seems that I have to run the SonarQube scanner to get such data. However, I don't want to do this, because I have to create a new project and the results will be displayed on the web page. So is there a way to run the Java analyzer immediately and provide relevant syntax and semantic data for a Java file?
Thanks a lot~

Comment: It will be easier to help you if you can share what are you trying to achieve? Why do you need syntax and semantic data and do not want to run the analysis?

Answer (score 0):

You can use plugins like sonarlint,which will show the issues for opened file on IDE itself.

Comment: Thanks~Can I write code calling APIs of sonarlint to analyze a Java file, and get the corresponding AST and semantic data? I have checked the project in GitHub, and didn't find such features. Could you please provide more information?

Comment: If you are using IntelliJ or Eclipse,plugin can be downloaded from www.sonarlint.org and can be configured by placing it in plugin folder.

Comment: @rathna consider editing your answer to include the information you added in your comment; the people who come later may not read the comments.